# MySQL Syntax Error using FROM

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am getting the following syntax error when running the below query.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM shorewarecdrarchive.connect         LEFT JOIN     shorewarecdrarchive.call ' at line 28

Line 28 is the **FROM** part of the query.

```
SELECT
    call.Extension,
    -- agentactivity.AgentDN,
    -- agentactivity.AgentFirstName,
    -- agentactivity.AgentLastName,
    -- agentactivity.WorkgroupDN,
    -- agentactivity.WorkgroupName,
    call.DialedNumber,
    connect.PartyID,
    call.CallerID,
    connect.PartyIDName,
    connect.PartyIDLastName,
    -- agentactivity.StartTimeStamp,
    call.StartTime,
    date(call.StartTime),
    time(call.StartTime),
    hour(call.StartTime),
    call.EndTime,
    -- agentactivity.EndTimeStamp,
    call.CallType,
    call.ID,
    connect.PartyType,
    connect.ConnectReason,
    connect.TalkTimeSeconds,
    connect.duration,
    call.duration,
    -- agentactivity.State
FROM shorewarecdrarchive.connect
LEFT JOIN
    shorewarecdrarchive.call ON connect.CallTableID = call.ID
-- LEFT JOIN
-- shorewarecdrarchive.agentactivity ON call.Extension = agentactivity.AgentDN
WHERE
-- StartTimestamp >= '2016-12-05 08:20:00'
-- AND StartTimestamp < '2016-12-05 08:40:00'
-- AND PartyIDName NOT IN ('Overhead Paging','Voice Mail','Voice Mail Login','Door','Door Intercom','Main Line Hunt Group','Main Line','Sales','ACT','Auto-Attendant','Night Bell','Backup Auto-Attendant','Dispatch','North', 'North Lunch')
-- AND WorkgroupName NOT IN ('Dispatch' , 'Main Line')
-- AND CallType between 1 and 3
-- Calltype 1 = Extension to extension call.
-- CallType 2 = A trunk is the originating party. (Inbound calls)
-- Calltype 3 = An extension is originating and a trunk is called. (Outbound calls)
-- CallType 4 = A call originating from a trunk and going to a trunk. (Tie trunks)
-- AND agentactivity.WorkgroupName = 'Sales' or'Pre-sales' or 'QFC Orders'
-- and call.id = '402300'
call.ID = '612916'
order by call.ID ASC;
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know what I am not seeing; I am pretty sure it's something simple, though I am having one of those *'to close to the painting'* situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
    call.duration,
-- agentactivity.State
FROM shorewarecdrarchive.connect
```

to

```
call.duration --removing the comma
-- agentactivity.State
FROM shorewarecdrarchive.connect
```

or

```
call.duration,
agentactivity.State --uncommenting this line
FROM shorewarecdrarchive.connect
```

The problem is the trailing comma at the end of call.duration